# PHP export mysql data to excel sheet

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I have a filter that the user selects or inputs information, and when they hit submit, a query is generated with this code:

```
 <?php 
 function displayrecords(){
   $data1 = $_POST['data1'];
   $data2 = $_POST['data2'];
   $data3 = $_POST['data3'];
   $sql_json = "";
   $where = "";
   if($data1 != ""){
     $where = " `data1` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($data1)."'";
   }
   if($data2 != ""){
     if ( $where != "" ) $where .= " AND ";
     $where = " `data2` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($data2)."'";
   }
   if($data3 != ""){
     if ( $where != "" ) $where .= " AND ";
     $where = " `data3` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($data3)."'";
   }
   if ($where != "") $sql_json = "SELECT * FROM `database`" . " WHERE " . $where . ";";
   $QueryResult = @mysql_query($sql_json) or die (mysql_error());

   echo "<table>"
   echo "<tr><th>Data1</th>" . "<th>Data2</th>" . "<th>Data3</th></tr>\n";
   while(($Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($QueryResult)) !== FALSE) {
   echo "<tr><td>{$Row['data1']}</td>";
   echo "<td>{$Row['data2']}</td>";
   echo "<td>{$Row['data3']}</td></tr>\n";
   };
   echo "</table>"\n";
   }
 }
```

It then spits the data out with this:

```
 <?php displayrecords(); ?>
```

There are no issues here.  The query builder works.  The data is rendered to the screen in the table.

What I need to do now is take the data that has been returned to the screen and export it to an excel sheet using another button in the same form as the other submit button. Here is the button that is in the same form:

```
 <input class="btn btn-success btn-small" type="submit" name="get_report" value="Get Report" />
```

I don't know if I can use another submit button in the same form. I think on have to use a javascript onclick() function.  I'm not sure.  I just need to export the returned data to excel.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using the creaky, antiquated `mysql_query` interface? As you've demonstrated here, it's super clunky and awkward to use compared to a modern replacement like PDO.

Comment: My next application, I will utilize PDO. Until then, would you have an answer to my issue?

Comment: Your last `echo` in your first code block there looks likely to throw a parsing error.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to consider:

Don't use `$_POST[]` within a function.  It limits the function to only dealing with POST.  Rather, call the function with your POST data.

Have the data retrieved from the database and returned in its own function, something like `getTableData()`, so that your HTML and your spreadsheet scripts will be able to query the data independently without redundant code.

Also, it is always recommended to use `mysqli_` or PDO over `mysql_*`, as `mysql_` is deprecated.

I will not address the database query or the html table display in this answer, as it seems you are quite capable of handling that aspect of the task on your own.

With all that in mind, my method would be the following:

At the end of the HTML table, place a link to a csv file in a subdirectory like so:

```
<a href='download/some.csv?<?php echo 'data1='.urlencode($_POST['data1'], ENT_QUOTES).'&amp;data2='.urlencode($_POST['data2'], ENT_QUOTES).'&amp;data3='.urlencode($_POST['data3'], ENT_QUOTES).; ?>'>Download CSV</a>
```

Then, in your `download` folder, you'll need a `.htaccess` file with the following contents:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ getFile.php?file=$0 [QSA,L]
```

Also in your `download` folder, you'll place a `getFile.php` file that may look something like this:

```
<?php

$fileName = (isset($_GET['file'])) ? $_GET['file'] : false;
$data1 = (isset($_GET['data1'])) ? $_GET['data1'] : false;
$data2 = (isset($_GET['data2'])) ? $_GET['data2'] : false;
$data3 = (isset($_GET['data3'])) ? $_GET['data3'] : false;

if($fileName && $data = getTableData($data1, $data2, $data3)) //This would be calling your new function designed specifically to retrieve your data in a multidimensional array
{
    header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
    header("Content-Type: text/csv");
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fileName.'"');
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
    foreach($data as $row)
    {
        foreach($row as $columnCount=>$field)
        {
            echo ($columnCount) ? ','.csvField($field) : csvField($field);
        }
        echo "\r\n";
    }
}
else header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");

function csvField($value, $textDelimiter = '"')
{
    if (strstr($value, $textDelimiter) || strstr($value, ",")) $value = $textDelimiter.str_replace($textDelimiter, $textDelimiter.$textDelimiter, $value).$textDelimiter;
    return $value;
}

?>
```

the `.htaccess` file passes the file name to your `getFile.php` script in a `$_GET` parameter.  Your .csv file *must not actually exist*, so that `.htaccess` can redirect the request to `getFile.php`.

Make sure that in your `getTableData()` function the variables passed are properly protected against SQL injection.